# Use echo to empty file content in Windows Command Prompt

Tags: windows, append, echo, command-prompt, shrink

I have a folder on a windows laptop running a program for measuring concrete vibrations that runs 24/7.
The software creates 2 files every 10 minutes *.asx and *.pbx
The *.pbx files becomes 28 MB each.
I run backup from the laptop to an ftp server every night.
I would need to empty the files of its data, tried with echo and that works.
but its thousands of files and i cannot figure out how to do it on all *.pbx extensions.
Cannot remove the files, because then program will then restart the number sequence after 10 min.
I need to keep all files in the directory just need to shrink them.
The data in the files are not important after backup is finished.

I have tried
echo delete >*.pbx and most of the arguments.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `FOR /F` - [loop command: against the results of another command](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html).

From command prompt:

```
for /f "delims=" %G in ('dir /B *.pbx') do @copy /Y NUL "%~G">NUL
```

From a Windows batch script (`.bat` or `.cmd`)

```
@for /f "delims=" %%G in ('dir /B *.pbx') do @copy /Y NUL "%%~G">NUL
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! This really worked like a charm!
Exactly what I was wishing for!
A lot of karma sent your way!

Answer (score 0):

To empty a file, you can use copy:

```
copy /Y nul: myfile.myext
```